# Fade in an image based on class selected

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have a menu where each menu item has a class.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="selected">Choose a team</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="ari">Arizona Cardinals</li>
            <li class="atl">Atlanta Falcons</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I also have a series of images that live in uniques divs with the same id as the class in the menu. They are at opacity .25 to start.

```
<div id="ari" class="teamChart"></div>
<div id="atl" class="teamChart"></div>
```

When I select an item in the menu, I'm trying to use the class name to call the id name so I can fade it in. Something like this...

```
$('#nav li ul li').click(function(){
    $youPicked = '"#'+$(this).attr('class')+'"';

            alert($youPicked); 
            //displays "#ari" when clicked.

            $($youPicked).css('position', 'absolute');
            //hopefully will bring it to front

            //hoping to fadeIn
            $($youPicked).fadeTo('slow',1, function(){
                  //fadeIn complete
            });
});
```

If I can get it to work, great. Or perhaps there's a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need in double quotes for `$youPicked` variable. You can rewrite your code as follows.

```
$("#nav ul li").click(function() {
    var el = $("#" + this.className);
    el.css("position", "absolute");
    el.fadeTo("slow", 1, function() {
        //fadeIn complete
    });
});
```

BTW, I doubt if there is a need to do absolute positioning. Try first without.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do it like,

```
$('#nav li ul li').click(function(){
    $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
    $(this).fadeTo('slow',1, function(){
         //fadeIn complete
    });
});
```